# Scanning the output of a program at shell

Tags: linux, shell, output

Hello I am currently trying to make a script file in Linux that has as input the output of o prgram and scans it to find how many occurences of some words are existed. To be clearer I want to scan the output and store to variables how many times some words exist in that output. I am new to scripitin in linux. I tried storing the output in a file and then scan it line by line in order to find the words but for somre reason the loop i use to parse it never ends. Can you help me?

```
./program > buffer.txt

while read LINE
do
echo $LINE | grep word1  #when i use grep command the loop never ends
done <a.txt
```

Edit: In C an equivalent program would be

```
char* word="word1"
while(/*parse all the lines at a text */)
{
fgetline("file_a",&buffer)
if(strcmp(buffer,word)==0)
 strcpy(word1,"word") //continue the search with this 
}
```

Comment: you're writing to buffer.txt and reading from a.txt. Is that right?

Comment: @dogbane yes it thes best idea i came up with. But this script never ends! It continues to infinity. If i make it echo $line it works fine

Comment: I don't see the point of this loop. Why not simply use `grep word1 a.txt` instead of the loop? There is something you are not showing us.

Comment: @dogbane because i want to use an if statement that alters the word that i want find after the first occurence of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest thing to do is to skip writing to a file altogether

```
if ./program | grep -q word1 &>/dev/null; then
    echo "TRUE"
fi
```

-q tells grep to be quiet, but it can still produce error messages occasionally which you can suppress w/the &>/dev/null.  If you'd prefer to see any error messages, just remove that part.
If you want ./program's errors and stdout to be analyzed by grep then you'll need to redirect stderr to stdout like [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine,
the while loop will exit.
try adding the following line after the while loop and verify

echo "While loop Exited!"